# convert unknown file type readable by notepad to .csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have 300 files with extension `.EMA` (never seen before) that I would like to convert to `.csv` files. The files are perfectly readable in Notepad. However, I need to convert them to `.csv` files as I want to read them with Python.

Does anyone know how to convert the files in a quick way?

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what's in those files or what their format is like, we can't tell you how to put the data into a different format.

Comment: Where did the files come from?  Do you have a spec of their format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension doesn't determine the file contents. Both  `.csv` and your file can be opened in notepad because they are text files. You don't have to do anything in this case - just use the file with .EMEA extension and it will work same thing as .csv

EDIT:

New information from comments seems to indicate the file is a csv-like file but using `|` as separator instead of the comma; if you're using pandas, try using

```
pd.read_csv('file.EMEA', delimiter='|')
```

Comment: Assuming there's actually CSV-formatted data in those files, anyway. The question says it's "perfectly readable" in Notepad, but that doesn't mean it's CSV.

Comment: @user2357112 I mean that python can open any file, regardless of the extension. Python can open non-csv files too.

Comment: Certainly true, but processing the data will have to be done differently for CSV or non-CSV. You can't just pass it to `csv.reader` or `pandas.read_csv` or whatever you would have used with a CSV file. Opening the file and getting raw bytes or characters out is only a small part of the story.

Comment: @user2357112 maybe it is a csv file, who knows - the OP seems confused about the extension, and I am clarifying that the extension is unrelated

Comment: The problem with Notepad is that it tends to ignore characters it can't understand, just because it is "perfectly readable" doesn't mean it is all ASCII text.

Comment: I tried this. It gives the same result as without the file conversion (so this answer is consistent). I can read the file as a DataFrame but the object does not clearly contain the data. I am able to read the number of records (5536) but I cannot access entries. 

Possibly the file is wrecked ... I understand this is hard to answer for you guys.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an excerpt with some lines from the file so we can take a look

Comment: Typically one line is as follows:

CD.FW.003121|CF|USD|FO|OBROTFB|20170929|SEP17|20170102|171500|515.239644335|515.239644335|515.239644335|Source|Passed

Comment: It seems a csv file using `|` as separator instead of the comma `,`; try using `read_csv('file.EMEA', delimiter='|')`

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit stupid. I forgot the delimiter ....